# Currency launch probability

Tags: probability

Two individuals, $ A $ and $ B $ will play heads or tails with an '' honest '' coin. They agree to flip the coin $ 5 $ times, and the one who wins in 3 or more rolls wins the game. Each bets $ 2800$. After the first two launches, in which both $ A $ wins, they decide to end the game. From a probabilistic point of view, how should the 5600 dollars be distributed?

Solution: The probability that B will win the next three rolls is $\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac18$. So the dollars should be distributed in a $1:7$ ratio. This means that A will get $4900$ dollars, and B will get $700$ dollars.

Is this solution correct? Why would the ratio be 1: 7? Could someone explain it to me better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $A$ player is [risk neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Example) then he will accept the expected value of the game not to play which is

$$E_A = \frac{7}{8}\cdot5600+\frac{1}{8}\cdot0 = 4900$$

A similar reasoning can be used with $B$. The ratio can be seen to originate from this reasoning.

Consider also that the expected value measures how much the player would win on average partecipating at the game.

Answer (score 1):

At the time they decided to end the game, if they continued then the odds of a win for A are 50%. For B are 12.5% because it needs to win the next 3 events of coin toss.

We need a pondered average. Since 50% is 4x12.5%, then A takes 4 times the amount B takes.

A takes 4480 while B takes the rest, 1120.

Comment: Why don't you consider the other $2$ events for $A$?

Comment: If they continued to play, A will retain 50% chance to win in events 3, 4, 5 while B will see his chance increasing from 12.5% in event 3 to 25% in event 4 to 50% in event 5. However, they didn’t play. So the decisive should be not on what they didn’t play but on what they played.